# Install software from a non-Ubuntu iso file

Tags: software-installation, iso

I have a DVD, which has an iso file in it. It's not an Ubuntu DVD, it's another iso file with some software in it. How can I install this software in Ubuntu? I know this is kind of stupid question. I'm just new to Ubuntu and have googled a lot of solutions. Most of them are about how to burn an iso file to a CD.

Comment: @karel, I already have Ubuntu system. I want to install some software in Ubuntu

Comment: If the software that you want to install is open source software, you're probably going to have to search for the Linux binary of the software that you want to install and then compile it. Or maybe there's even a .deb file of the software out there that would be easier for you to install.

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-to-install-applications-in-ubuntu/307286#307286

Comment: The reason most of them are about how to burn an .iso to a cd is because that's typically what you do with .iso files in order to access the contents. You can also mount them as a loop device. see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountIso Please help us help you by providing more information about what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and any other pertinent information you can provide. Thank you!